# Long term health effects of a gsm modem

Tags: gsm, radiation, modem

We all use internet through our mobile phones hence gsm infrastructure. I know the radiation exposure is higher than wifi. That's why I preffer wifi over mobile whereever i can.

However I'm currently interested in a 4g modem. I actually think placing it at a safe distance would be enough to avoid the potential risks yet I'm not sure about it. In short, by having a 4g modem at home how much risk do we take? Am I right about my assumption?

Comment: No, you are wrong. We don't **all** use internet through our phones. The tools I need are not available on a phone.

Answer (score 5):

The fears are unfounded - both technologies are fundamentally safe. The only conceivable damage from radio waves is heating of biological tissue and and Specific Absorption Rate (SAR) testing is specifically designed to ensure no harmful exposure levels to humans in nearby usage and Maximum Permissible Exposure (MPE) at distances past 20cm.

"In the United States, the FCC regulates SAR under 47 CFR Part 2, section 2.1093.  Products intended for general use must meet a SAR limit of 1.6 mW/g averaged over one gram of tissue in any part of the head or body, and 4 mW/g averaged over 10 grams for hands, wrists, feet and ankles.

In the European Union, RF exposure limits have been established by Council Recommendation 1999/519/EC.  Harmonized standards cover the most common products such as cell phones and RFID devices.  The limits and methods of RF exposure evaluation in the EU are similar but not identical to those in the US."

"In the United States, the FCC rules for MPE limits are found in 47 CFR Part 2, section 1.1310.  Mobile devices, which are more than 20 cm from the user and are not in a fixed location, such as tabletop wireless nodes, are also governed by section 2.1091 of the FCC rules.

In the European Union, Council Recommendation 1999/519/EC contains the exposure limits for fixed and mobile transmitters.  The harmonized standard EN50385 applies limits to base stations operating in the frequency range 110MHz to 40 GHz."
[source](http://www.intertek.com/wireless/sar-testing/)